# Does the Booming Blade spell's damage from moving trigger before or after an opportunity attack?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, opportunity-attack

I hit an enemy with *booming blade*, and before my next turn they chose to move away, provoking an opportunity attack. Does the *booming blade*'s damage-on-movement trigger before or after I make my opportunity attack?

Answer (score 12):

The Booming Blade effect triggers before the opportunity attack.

Booming Blade states:

> If the target willingly moves before then, it **immediately** takes 1d8
>   thunder damage, and the spell ends.

Opportunity Attack states:

> You can make an opportunity attack when a hostile creature that you
>   can see moves out of your reach. To make the opportunity attack, you
>   use your reaction to make one melee attack against the provoking
>   creature. The attack interrupts the provoking creature’s movement,
>   occurring **right before the creature leaves your reach**.

**Emphasis mine**

The creature first begins to move, triggering the Booming Blade and then, right before it leaves your reach, the opportunity attack triggers.

Of course this is all assuming you have not spent your reaction, your reach is 5ft and the enemy attempts to immediately leave your reach instead of moving around you.

Answer (score 5):

### Booming Blade triggers first.

Let's start with quotes from the specific abilities:

*[Booming Blade](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/booming-blade)* says:

> If the target willingly moves before then, it immediately takes 1d8 thunder damage, and the spell ends.

*[Opportunity Attack](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/combat#OpportunityAttacks)* says:

> The attack interrupts the provoking creature’s movement, occurring right before the creature leaves your reach.

When not using a grid, a character stepping even one foot away has "willingly move[d]" and triggers *Booming Blade*. *An opportunity attack* follows if they continue to move and "leaves [the other character's] reach".

[Fighting on a grid](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/dmg/running-the-game#UsingMiniatures) is an optional rule, and shouldn't have any material effect on how a spell plays out. It's more granular nature should not change the order things trigger. In effect, as soon as the victim declares their intention to move on a grid, *Booming Blade* triggers. The *Opportunity Attack* triggers when their movement is about to carry them to a square outside the character's reach, but before it actually happens (relevant for things like [Sentinel](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/phb/customization-options#Sentinel)).

### Related "Trick"

Combine *Booming Blade* with *[War Caster](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/feats/war-caster)*. Hit the target with *Booming Blade* on your turn. If they move, they take the damage. When they provoke an opportunity attack, hit them with it again. If they keep moving, they take the damage again.

Comment: Thank you. My question was actually prompted specifically by the situation you described as a Related "Trick".

Comment: I do it as often as I can manage on my Paladin Sorcerer. When possible, I take my two normal attacks then quicken a Booming Blade for a third. Any or all of them could be Smites, too. Roll in a *Champion Challenge* from Oath of the Crown, or *Compelled Duel* out of a normal spell slot, and they can't run farther than I can catch them anyway.

Comment: Related to your "Trick". If a creature is moving out, triggers the Opportunity attack, and you hit them with Booming Blade, can they choose to stop moving or since they were already moving when you hit them they would automatically take the secondary damage?

Comment: @DragoonKite The target takes the rider damage for moving the instant they start moving, whether they provoke or not (the target could move within the caster's reach). War Caster triggers when the target steps outside the caster's reach, allowing the caster to make another Booming Blade attack. If it hits, the target takes the initial damage immediately and then decides whether or not to keep moving. On a grid, they're in the square just beyond the caster's reach, because if they didn't get that far, they never left the caster's reach and wouldn't have provoked in the first place.

Comment: Thanks. That's how I figured it worked I just wanted to make sure.